# Derivative of a matrix wrt a vector

Tags: linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus

Suppose that

$y(q) = A(q) x(q), \; A:\mathbb R^k \rightarrow \mathbb R^{m \times n}, \; x \in \mathbb R^n, \; y \in \mathbb R^m, \; q \in \mathbb R^k$

then, the partial derivative of this expression wrt to $q$ is

$\underbrace{\frac{\partial y(q)}{\partial q}}_{m \times k} = \underbrace{\frac{\partial A(q)}{\partial q} x(q)}_{m \times k} + \underbrace{A(q) \frac{\partial x(q)}{\partial q}}_{m \times k}$

I am not sure how to treat the first term of the the right hand side. My intuition says that if

$\frac{\partial A(q)}{\partial q} \in \Re^{m \times n \times k}$

then

$\frac{\partial A(q)}{\partial q}x(q) = \Big[\frac{\partial A(q)}{\partial q_1}x(q);...;\frac{\partial A(q)}{\partial q_k}x(q)\Big]$

where the product of each individual term ($\frac{\partial A(q)}{\partial q_i}x(q)$) is the $i$th column. Is this the right way to treat this type of operations, and what kind of multiplication is this?

Comment: Is $A$ a vector-valued or a matrix-valued function ?

Comment: $A$ is a matrix of dimensions $m \times n$ which is a function of $q$.

Comment: The notation $A(q)$ suggests $A$ is a function. Would it be:
$$ A \, : \, \mathbb{R}^{k} \, \rightarrow \, \mathrm{Mat}\big( (m,n), \mathbb{R} \big) $$ 
?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's normally easier understand what the derivative is if we use the definition that if $f: \mathbb{R}^m \supseteq U \to \mathbb{R}^n$, the derivative  is the unique linear map $ Df_x : \mathbb{R}^m \to \mathbb{R}^n $ so that
$$ f(x+h)-f(x) = Df_x(h) + o(\lvert h \rvert). $$
This still works if we replace $\mathbb{R}^n$ by some other finite-dimensional real vector space. Then from uniqueness we have the product rule
$$ f(x+h)g(x+h)-f(x)g(x) = (Df_x(h))g(x)+f(x)(Dg_x(h))+ o(\lvert h \rvert) = D(fg)_x(h) + o(\lvert h \rvert), $$
and in particular, $Df_x(h)$ and $Dg_x(h)$ are the same type of object as $f$ and $g$, so the multiplication is the same as that between $f$ and $g$.

So, if $f=A: \mathbb{R}^k \to \text{Mat}(n,m) \cong \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$ and $g=x: \mathbb{R}^k \to \mathbb{R}^n$, we have
$$ Dy_q(h) = (DA_q(h))x(q) + A(q)Dx_q(h) $$
Writing this in components,
$$ [Dq_(h)]_i = \sum_{j=1}^k [Dy_q]_{ij}h_j = \sum_{j=1}^k \sum_{l=1}^n [DA_q]_{ilj} h_j x_l + [A(q)]_{il}[Dx_q]_{lj}h_j \\
= \sum_{j=1}^k\sum_{l=1}^n \partial_j [A(q)]_{il} h_j [x(q)]_l + [A(q)]_{il} [Dx_q]_{lj} h_j \\
\implies [Dy_q]_{ij} = \sum_{p=1}^n \partial_j [A(q)]_{il} [x(q)]_l + [A(q)]_{il} [Dx_q]_{lj}. $$

Comment: Thank you for your comment. The summation notation is a bit confusing (for me). Is it possible to re-express the final equation in a matrix vector form?

Comment: The problem is that $\partial_j [A(q)]_{ik}$ has three indices (two in and one output), which means you can't write it down in pure matrix notation since there aren't enough places to put the inputs. You can write it using directional derivatives $(h \cdot \nabla) = \sum_j h_j \partial_j $ as $$ (h \cdot \nabla)y(q) = ((h \cdot \nabla)A(q))x(q) + A(q) ((h\cdot \nabla)x(q)), $$ since the directional derivative outputs the same type of object as the input, so $(h \cdot \nabla)A(q)$ is a matrix, for example.

Comment: Does this confirm my assumption, $\frac{\partial A(q)}{\partial q}x(q) = \Big[\frac{\partial A(q)}{\partial q_1}x(q);...;\frac{\partial A(q)}{\partial q_k}x(q)\Big] \in \mathbb R^{m \times k}$, where ';' is a column separator?

Comment: Yes, that appears to be correct.

Answer (score 0):

If $\mathbf{A} \, : \, \mathbb{R}^k \, \mapsto \, \mathrm{Mat}\big( (m,n), \mathbb{R} \big)$, $\mathbf{x} \, : \, \mathbb{R}^k \, \mapsto \, \mathbb{R}^n$ and $\mathbf{y} \, : \, \mathbb{R}^k \, \mapsto \, \mathbb{R}^m$ are differentiable on $\mathbb{R}^k$, then, for $\mathbf{q} \in \mathbb{R}^{k}$, you can indeed write:

$$ \frac{\partial \mathbf{y}}{\partial \mathbf{q}}(\mathbf{q}) = \frac{\partial \mathbf{A}}{\partial \mathbf{q}}(\mathbf{q})\mathbf{x}(\mathbf{q}) + \mathbf{A}(\mathbf{q}) \frac{\partial \mathbf{x}}{\partial \mathbf{q}}(\mathbf{q}). $$

If $\mathbf{q}=\begin{bmatrix} q_1 & \ldots & q_k \end{bmatrix}^{\top}$, then, you could say that:

$$ \frac{\partial \mathbf{A}}{\partial \mathbf{q}}(\mathbf{q}) = \sum_{i=1}^{k} q_i\frac{\partial \mathbf{A}}{\partial q_i}(\mathbf{q}) \in \mathrm{Mat}\big( (m,n), \mathbb{R} \big) $$

and therefore:

$$ \frac{\partial \mathbf{A}}{\partial \mathbf{q}}(\mathbf{q}) \mathbf{x}(\mathbf{q}) = \sum_{i=1}^{k} q_i \frac{\partial \mathbf{A}}{\partial q_i}(\mathbf{q}) \mathbf{x}(\mathbf{q}) \in \mathbb{R}^m. $$

Comment: Thank you for your comment. If this term is a vector in $\mathbb R^m$ then the second equations does not hold. This product must be a matrix of dimensions $\mathbb R^{m \times k}$

Comment: It depends on how you define $\partial \mathbf{y}/\partial \mathbf{q}$. If $D_{\mathbf{q}}\mathbf{y}$ is the differential of $\mathbf{y}$ at $\mathbf{q}$:
$$ \forall \mathbf{s} \in \mathbb{R}^k, \; \frac{\partial \mathbf{y}}{\partial \mathbf{q}}(\mathbf{s}) = D_{\mathbf{q}} \mathbf{y}(\mathbf{s}\big) = \lim \limits_{t \to 0} \frac{ \mathbf{y}(\mathbf{s} + t \mathbf{q}) - \mathbf{y}(\mathbf{s})}{t}. $$
Therefore:
$$ \frac{\partial \mathbf{y}}{\partial \mathbf{q}}(\mathbf{q}) = \sum_{i=1}^k q_i \frac{\partial \mathbf{y}}{\partial q_i}(\mathbf{q}) $$
which is an equality in $\mathbb{R}^m$.

Comment: If $y \in \mathbb R^m$ and $q \in \mathbb R^k$, shouldn't $\frac{\partial y}{\partial q} \in \mathbb R^{m \times k}$ be the Jacobian?

Comment: Yes, you could use this notation for the jacobian of $\mathbf{y}$. The jacobian of $\mathbf{y}$ is, indeed, a $m \times k$ matrix. However, $\big( \partial \mathbf{y} / \partial \mathbf{q} \big)(\mathbf{q})$ is not the jacobian. It can be seen as a "matrix-vector" product.